# Sharepoint Kerberos and...... search?

Tags: search, authentication, kerberos

I'm troubleshooting some kerberos issues with Sharepoint and turned on kerberos logging.  I'm getting -

+++

A Kerberos Error Message was received:

on logon session

Client Time:

Server Time: 2:47:14.0000 4/20/2014 Z

Error Code: 0x1b Unknown Error

Extended Error:

Client Realm:

Client Name:

Server Realm: DOMAIN.LOCAL

Server Name: sp-search

Target Name: sp-search@DOMAIN.LOCAL

Error Text:

File: 9

Line: f09

Error Data is in record data.

++++

The ONLY place I've configured that account is on the Search Host Controller service.  Does it make any sense to anyone?  Why should that account need to be delegated?

Comment: No, that's really weird. 110% sure it's not being used by another account? Does this error occur when the crawl is running? The TechNet article does not mention search at all: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806870(v=office.15).aspx